# Windows Server 2012: Cannot install SMTP-Server, system always requires restart

Tags: smtp, windows-server-2012

I'm not able to install the "SMTP-Server" feature on a Windows 2012 server. The installation process always fails with a "restart required" message. After the restart and (re)starting the SMTP-Server feature, the system requires a new restart.

I tried to install the feature using the installation wizard and PowerShell.

When trying to install the feature using PowerShell the error looks as follows:

```
PS > Install-WindowsFeature SMTP-Server
Install-WindowsFeature : Fehler bei der Anforderung zum Hinzufügen oder Entfernen von Features auf dem angegebenen
Server.
Der Vorgang kann nicht abgeschlossen werden, da der angegebene Server neu gestartet werden muss.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Install-WindowsFeature SMTP-Server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : DeviceError: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature], Exce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_Reboot_Required,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindow
   sFeatureCommand

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
False   No             Failed         {}
```

Using the Get-PendingReboot script from here https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-PendingReboot-Query-bdb79542 shows the following pending restart status after trying to install the feature:

```
CBServicing    : True
WindowsUpdate  : False
CCMClientSDK   : False
PendFileRename : False
PendFileRenVal :
RebootPending  : True
```

After a reboot and before starting the SMTP-Server installation, there is no pending restart, i.e. the script shows (RebootPending  : False).

After an unsuccessful installation process I even cannot list the Windows features:

```
PS > Get-WindowsFeature
Get-WindowsFeature : Fehler bei der Anforderung zum Auflisten der auf dem angegebenen Server verfügbaren Features.
Der Vorgang kann nicht abgeschlossen werden, da der angegebene Server neu gestartet werden muss.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Get-WindowsFeature
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : DeviceError: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Get-WindowsFeature], Deployme
   ntProviderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetEnumerationState_Failed_Reboot_Required,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.GetW
   indowsFeatureCommand
```

dism.exe /online /get-features reports the following:

```
Tool zur Imageverwaltung für die Bereitstellung
Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Abbildversion: 6.2.9200.16384

Featureauflistung für das Paket : Microsoft-Windows-ServerCore-Package~31bf3856a
d364e35~amd64~~6.2.9200.16384

Featurename : NetFx3ServerFeatures
Status : Aktiviert


Fehler: 3017

Der angeforderte Vorgang war nicht erfolgreich. Es ist ein Systemneustart erford
erlich, um die durchgeführten Änderungen rückgängig zu machen.

Die DISM-Protokolldatei befindet sich unter "C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log".
```

The following lines are logged in C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log:

```
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=4852 TID=5124 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4852 TID=5124 Processing the top level command token(get-features). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4852 TID=5124 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4852 TID=5124 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4852 TID=5124 Feature NetFx3ServerFeatures with CBS state 7(CbsInstallStateInstalled) being mapped to dism state 7(DISM_INSTALL_STATE_INSTALLED) - CDISMPackageFeature::LogInstallStateMapping
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4852 TID=5124 Failed to get the State of the Feature - CDISMPackageFeature::Internal_GetCbsState(hr:0x80070bc9)
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4852 TID=5124 Failed to get the CBS State of the Feature - CDISMPackageFeature::get_State(hr:0x80070bc9)
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4852 TID=5124 Failed to get the feature state. - CCBSFormatter::PrintCbsFeatures_ListFormat(hr:0x80070bc9)
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4852 TID=5124 Failed while processing command get-features. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80070bc9)
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4852 TID=5124 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=80070BC9
```

The following lines are logged in C:\Windows\logs\CBS\cbs.log:

```
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    TI: --- Initializing Trusted Installer ---
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    TI: Last boot time: 2015-06-28 15:46:57.314
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    TrustedInstaller terminated with pending operations.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller initialization.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller initialization.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Starting the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    TrustedInstaller service starts successfully.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Registering for Winlogon CreateSession notifications
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Registering for pre-shutdown notification to complete the pended operation
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Startup processing thread terminated normally
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Starting TiWorker initialization.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Ending TiWorker initialization.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Starting the TiWorker main loop.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    TiWorker starts successfully.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Universal Time is: 2015-06-28 19:35:58.771
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Loaded Servicing Stack v6.2.9200.17280 with Core: C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.17280_none_6224eed751126779\cbscore.dll
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CSI    00000001@2015/6/28:19:35:58.771 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7f950ce63c1 @0x7f9570198ba @0x7f956fd4dd4 @0x7f684d3d1df @0x7f684d3d95c @0x7f96b8e1d35)
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Could not load SrClient DLL from path: SrClient.dll.  Continuing without system restore points.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CSI    00000002@2015/6/28:19:35:58.771 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7f950ce63c1 @0x7f957076248 @0x7f957037719 @0x7f956fd4f47 @0x7f684d3d1df @0x7f684d3d95c)
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    SQM: Initializing online with Windows opt-in: False
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    SQM: Cleaning up report files older than 10 days.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    SQM: Requesting upload of all unsent reports.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    SQM: Failed to start upload with file pattern: C:\Windows\servicing\sqm\*_std.sqm, flags: 0x2 [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    SQM: Failed to start standard sample upload. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    SQM: Queued 0 file(s) for upload with pattern: C:\Windows\servicing\sqm\*_all.sqm, flags: 0x6
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    SQM: Warning: Failed to upload all unsent reports. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Session: 30454233_2827951091 initialized by client DISM Package Manager Provider.
2015-06-28 21:35:58, Info                  CBS    Enumerating Foundation package: Microsoft-Windows-ServerCore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.9200.16384, this could be slow
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  CSI    00000003 CSI Store 1037981022800 (0x000000f1ac7d7a50) initialized
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  CSI    00000004 Transaction merge required, do-not-merge flag passed.
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  CSI    00000005@2015/6/28:19:35:59.604 CSI Transaction @0xf1ac867fb0 initialized for deployment engine {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} with flags 00000002 and client id [26]"TI5.30454233_2827951091:1/"

2015-06-28 21:35:59, Error                 CSI    00000006 (F) Current pending rollback transaction content precludes other operations; reboot to complete rollback.[gle=0x80004005]
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  CBS    Failed to get transaction analysis because of pending operations. Disposition from Analyze: 0x1 [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  CBS    Failed to get inventory. [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  CSI    00000007@2015/6/28:19:35:59.916 CSI Transaction @0xf1ac867fb0 destroyed
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  CBS    Failed to get CSI Inventory [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  CBS    Failed to get component state. [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  CBS    Failed to get current state of the deployment [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Info                  CBS    Failed to get Transaction State for package: Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-Server-OC-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.9200.16384, update: NetFx3 [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2015-06-28 21:35:59, Error                 CBS    Failed to get store state [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2015-06-28 21:37:59, Info                  CBS    Trusted Installer successfully registered to be restarted for pre-shutdown
2015-06-28 21:37:59, Info                  CBS    Trusted Installer is shutting down because: SHUTDOWN_REASON_AUTOSTOP
2015-06-28 21:37:59, Info                  CBS    Stopping Winlogon CreateSession notifications
2015-06-28 21:37:59, Info                  CBS    Unloading SysNotify DLL
2015-06-28 21:37:59, Info                  CBS    TiWorker signaled for shutdown, going to exit.
2015-06-28 21:37:59, Info                  CBS    Ending the TiWorker main loop.
2015-06-28 21:37:59, Info                  CBS    Starting TiWorker finalization.
2015-06-28 21:37:59, Info                  CBS    Ending the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2015-06-28 21:37:59, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller finalization.
2015-06-28 21:37:59, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller finalization.
2015-06-28 21:38:00, Info                  CBS    Ending TiWorker finalization.
```

I've no idea what causes the CBServicing to require a restart when installing the SMTP-Server feature nor how to fix the problem so that I'm able to install the SMTP-Server feature. Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: Normally the installation of the SMTP server setup does not require a restart of the server. Your problem may not even have anything to do with SMTP. Can you install anything else? Have a look at the dism logs at `C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log` as well.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your comment. I think you are right. After trying to install the SMTP server, event Get-WindowsFeatures does not work since it requires a restart. I've also added the logs from C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log to my question.

Comment: Those two log entries don't help. At least you know you have a bigger problem, not one with the STMP server :-( Look at the dism log again, I know lots of stuff in there, maybe there is some hint about a previous problem.  What's the error when you do: `dism.exe /online /get-features`

Comment: Hi @PeterHahndorf, thanks again for your feedback. I've edited the question and added some log information. Hope it helps...

Comment: So it seems there is a problem with the installation of `NetFx3ServerFeatures` - Can you try: `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

Comment: Thanks @PeterHahndorf, I tried `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` but unfortunately this did not fix the problem (server still requires restarts)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem: The cause was not the SMTP-Server feature itself but the  IIS-ODBCLogging feature that was required by the SMTP-Server. The installation of this IIS related feature failed due to a permission problem: It seemed that the installer had problems to update the IIS configuration which is stored on a network share (for sharing it between different servers in the web-farm).

In C:\Windows\iis.log I found:

```
[06/23/2015 13:28:58] [ ***** IIS 8.0 Component Based Setup ***** ]
[06/23/2015 13:28:58] "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iissetup.exe" /install Metabase
[06/23/2015 13:28:58] < WARNING! > Shared configuration detected. Install/Uninstall of optional component may fail. 
[06/23/2015 13:28:58] Successfully updated IIS_IUSRS rights.
[06/23/2015 13:28:58] Successfully populated IIS_IUSRS.
[06/23/2015 13:28:58] Successfully set IISADMIN install state.
[06/23/2015 13:28:58] Successfully removed old metabase files.
[06/23/2015 13:28:59] Successfully started IISADMIN.
[06/23/2015 13:28:59] < !!FAIL!! > MB::SetData result=0x80070005
[06/23/2015 13:28:59] < !!FAIL!! > METABASE_UTIL::InstallIisAdminMetabaseEntries result=0x80070005
[06/23/2015 13:29:05] Successfully stopped IISADMIN.
[06/23/2015 13:29:05] < !!FAIL!! > MB::SetData result=0x80070005
[06/23/2015 13:29:05] < WARNING! > METABASE_UTIL::InstallLegacySnapInMetabaseEntries result=0x80070005
[06/23/2015 13:29:05] Successfully started IISADMIN.
```

In the end disabling the IIS shared config, installing the feature and enabling the shared config again did the trick.

Comment: This came in handy for me. In my case, I saw the same error you did when trying to install SMTP. The root issue was the ODBCLogging feature install failing due to the configuration section being missing from the applicationHost.config file--something I had done prior in order to clean up the file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, but I was trying to install the DFS role instead of SMTP. In my situation, the issue was caused by permission issues with the Component Based Servicing (CBS) `%WINDIR%\WinSxS\pending.xml` list and a registry setting tied to it ( `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\PackagesPending`).

Essentially, the system could read the reg key and the pending actions list, but it couldn't modify them. I resolved the issue by taking ownership of the registry key and xml file and deleting both (made backups first,of course).

The powershell cmdlet that really helped me troubleshoot the issue was [Test-PendingReboot](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Test-PendingReboot/1.7/Content/Test-PendingReboot.ps1) which I ran from a Windows 10 workstation. It can be installed an used like so:

```
Install-Module PendingReboot
Test-PendingReboot -Detailed -ComputerName <yourServerHere>
```

The results showed that the forever pending reboot was due to ComponentBasedServicing, which finally let me figure out what was causing the issue. As soon as I deleted the registry key and the file, the system let me add the role and a ton of other issues were all resolved at once. When I did restart the server, it took an exceptionally long time to complete the shutdown portion of the restart. Been smooth sailing since then.